# How can I get 2c2e and 3c2e integrals using the erf kernel in PySCF?

Tags: pyscf, integrals

I want to reproduce the calculation procedure of density fitting in PySCF. I know how to get the 2c2e/3c2e integrals matrix/tensor with $1/r_{12}$ kernel by using `mol.intor('int2e')` and `df.incore.aux_e2(mol, auxmol)`. But it seems that the $\text{erf} (r_{12})/r_{12}$ kernel was not supported yet in two methods mentioned above. Is there a way to get the 2c2e/3c2e integrals matrix/tensor using the erf kernel?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Please update us!